# Is there a way to return comparator which wont do anything?

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have two classes extending one parent class and there is a method which sorts data by some parameter. So for one of these two classes, I need to apply some sorting but for two others don't do anything. Is there such possibility?

```
public class MedicalCompositeRatesData{

  @Override
  public List<RateTableData> buildData(RateTableInputBean inputBean)
  {
    SGQuotingData sgQuotingData = inputBean.getQuotingData();

    List<ProductData> products = extractorFactory
      .getProductExtractor(inputBean.getPlanType(), inputBean.getRatingType())
      .extract(sgQuotingData);

    List<Row> rates = products.stream()
        .map(it -> buildRow(it, sgQuotingData))
        .sorted(getProductComparator())
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return buildRateTables(rates);
  }

  protected Comparator<Product> getProductComparator(){
    //should leave default sorting
  }

}

public class AlternateCompositeRatesBuilder extends MedicalCompositeRatesData
{

  protected Comparator<Product> getProductComparator(){
    //will sort by rate
  }

}
```

Comment: Of course, don't implement the sorting method in the two other classes. Just keep it in the class you need it.

Comment: so saying 'don't implement sorting' do you mean to return some empty comparator?

Comment: its not entirely clear what you want to achieve here, may be a simpler example that we can look at? A comparator that does not do anything, you mean won't sort? If so, may be just return `zero` in that one all the time? thus making all entries the same

Comment: Somehow yeah, in your parent class you just make your Comparator function empty..and implement it in that child who needs it.. and I don't even see the use of it to be in the parent class if just one child out of 3 will use it

Comment: Probably returning zero should work. Let me check.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Stream.sort` makes a *stable* sort if the stream is ordered. In other words, if two elements are equals then they'll keep their initial ordering.

Thus, as your stream is made from a `List`, you can simply make all elements equal :

```
protected Comparator<Product> getProductComparator() {
    return (a1, a2) -> 0;
}
```

That's not very cool-looking though but it should do the job.

Comment: Since `null` references are being filtered out anyway, `.filter(Objects::nonNull).sorted(Comparator.nullsFirst(null))` will do the job as well, as it treats all non-`null` objects equally. Note that filtering before sorting may reduce the amount of work for sorting…

Comment: It's probably also noteworthy that sorting a `parallel` stream is [not](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8076446) always stable (though it should be).

Comment: @StefanZobel oh I didn't know... interesting :) anything that delegates to  Arrays.parallelSort can be affected (which is fairly often AFAIK)

Comment: @RonanDhellemmes Yes. The really depressing thing is that this doesn't get fixed in Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you have guava on the classpath, you could use:

```
Ordering.allEqual();
```

that internally does the same thing of returning zero...

```
@Override
public int compare(@Nullable Object left, @Nullable Object right) {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide some example on how will it work in my case if I'm using streams?

Comment: @user3298327 never mind... even guava is suggesting to use the lambda expression: `Use the lambda expression (a, b) -> 0 instead`

Comment: @AlexMalinovskiy `Ordering` is a subclass of `Comparator`. So it should work too. The reason why it does not work for you is that `getProductComparator`'s signature is wrong. It should be `protected Comparator<? super Product> getProductComparator()`